# Writing a program to write 3 grades, and then calculating the average, as well as showing the letter grades of the user input

Tags: c++

I am running into 3 errors in my code.
On line 12, it is saying that ": is ignored on left of 'const char' when no variable is declared
On line 29, '{': no matching token found.
On line 6, return type of 'main' should be 'int' instead of 'void'
My code is:

```
/*Write a program to read 3 grades. Grades are between 0-100. Calculate the average, then print the 
following message. */
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void main() {
int grade1{};
int grade2{};
int grade3{};
int average{};
int sum{};
const char;

cout << "Enter 3 grades (as a number between 0-100): " << endl;
cin >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3;
if (grade1 >= 90)
{
    cout << 'A' << endl;
}
if (grade1 <= 89)
{
    cout << 'B' << endl;
}
if (grade1 <= 79)
{
    cout << 'C' << endl;
}
if (grade1 <= 69)
{
    cout << 'D' << endl;
}
if (grade2 >= 90)
{
    cout << 'A' << endl;
}
if (grade2 <= 89)
{
    cout << 'B' << endl;
}
if (grade2 <= 79)
{
    cout << 'C' << endl;
}
if (grade2 <= 69)
{
    cout << 'D' << endl;
}
if (grade3 >= 90)
{
    cout << 'A' << endl;
}
if (grade3 <= 89)
{
    cout << 'B' << endl;
}
if (grade3 <= 79)
{
    cout << 'C' << endl;
}
if (grade3 <= 69)
{
    cout << 'D' << endl;
}
else
    cout << 'F' << endl;
sum = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3);
average = (sum / 3);
    cout << "Your average is: " << average << endl;
    }
```

Anyone know what I can do to fix these errors? Please help me out. Thank you! :)

Comment: 1) The sentence "return type of 'main' should be 'int' instead of 'void'" gives a pretty clear message, in my opinion. 2) There is nothing wrong with line 29. 3) Are you surprised that just writing a type, like `const char;`, is an error?

Comment: If you had written a `printGrade(int score)` function, you would only have had to write that code (and fix the output bug) once.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to use if-else-chains instead of if-chains (to avoid printing multiple letters)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `void main()` by `int main()` (that is just how C++ works). Also, what are you trying to do with `const char`? You are not declaring any variable and you are not using this line, so you can just remove it.

There is nothing wrong with line 29, after fixing the other two issues, the code works just fine.

Some further remarks:

- avoid `using namespace std`
- declare your variables at the first point you are using them. For example, write `int sum = grade1 + grade2 + grade3;`
- Try to avoid code duplication by writing a function that does the grading.
- Use `else if` instead of `if`, otherwise a number that is between 70 and 79 is also smaller than 89 and produces unwanted output.

Comment: I have ran it again now, it works, but I when I tried out putting three 100s in, it said AAA at the bottom, and it should have ended there. It added an extra letter after AAA and put F. Anybody know how to fix this? It does it for any other numbers as well. 100 100 100. Result is AAAF.

Comment: Because of ```else cout << 'F' << endl;``` This happens when the condition in the previous ```if``` is false. If you replace all but the first ```if``` by ```else if```. this will be fixed. So this happens when ```grade3 > 69```.

Comment: At the bottom, I have to output a certain message based on the information given. So if I put in 100 three times as my grades, I want it to output: Your average is: 100, your letter grade is: (A or B or C or D or F)"How do I make it output a letter grade based on the grades given? (By the way, I took out const char at the top). At the moment in the output, It shows three 100s in a row, and then the letter grade A, how do I move this letter grade to the next row where it says the message, "Your average is: 100, your letter grade is: "

Answer (score -1):

Regarding line 12, it seems that you are trying to declare a constant variable, but there is no name for the variable.

Regarding the error in line 6, the message explains what you could do to resolve it, change the return type of `main` to `int`.

Regarding line 29, I don't think there is an error.